# Text inside video

Tags: html, css

I want to add a video on my website at the header. How can I do that? If I use the "video source" on first, then it displays only my video. If not, I use the div class header first then my video disappears. I try to fix it in a couple ways but I didn't manage it. I just want to add my video on the header and in my video while is playing,to have the text seem "website".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
                <title>My website </title>
         <style type="text/css">
           * {
          box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        
        /* Style the body */
        body {
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          margin: 0;
        }
        //I want only in header to add my video ,.background-wrap  how to do it?
        /* Header/logo Title */
        .header {
          padding: 80px;
          text-align: center;
          background: #1abc9c;
          color: white;
        }
        
        /* Increase the font size of the heading */
        .header h1 {
          font-size: 40px;
        }
        
        /* Style the top navigation bar */
        .navbar {
          overflow: hidden;
          background-color: #333;
        }
        
        /* Style the navigation bar links */
        .navbar a {
          float: left;
          display: block;
          color: white;
          text-align: center;
          padding: 14px 20px;
          text-decoration: none;
        }
        
        /* Right-aligned link */
        .navbar a.right {
          float: right;
        }
        
        /* Change color on hover */
        .navbar a:hover {
          background-color: #ddd;
          color: black;
        }
        
        /* Column container */
        .row {  
          display: -ms-flexbox; /* IE10 */
          display: flex;
          -ms-flex-wrap: wrap; /* IE10 */
          flex-wrap: wrap;
        }
        
        /* Create two unequal columns that sits next to each other */
        /* Sidebar/left column */
        .side {
          -ms-flex: 30%; /* IE10 */
          flex: 30%;
          background-color: #f1f1f1;
          padding: 20px;
        }
        
        /* Main column */
        .main {   
          -ms-flex: 70%; /* IE10 */
          flex: 70%;
          background-color: white;
          padding: 20px;
        }
        
        /* Fake image, just for this example */
        .fakeimg {
          background-color: #aaa;
          width: 100%;
          padding: 20px;
        }
        
        /* Footer */
        .footer {
          padding: 20px;
          text-align: center;
          background: #ddd;
        }
        
        /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 700px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
        @media screen and (max-width: 700px) {
          .row {   
            flex-direction: column;
          }
        }
        
        /* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 400px wide, make the navigation links stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
        @media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
          .navbar a {
            float: none;
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
           
           
           
           
           
           
           
           
           
           * {
               margin: 0;
               padding: 0;
               }
               body {
            font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
        }
        .background-wrap {
            position:fixed;
            z-index:-1000;
            width:100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow:hidden;
            top:0; 
            left:0;
        }
        
        
        #video-bg-elem {
            position: absolute;
            top:0;
            left:0;
            min-height:100%;
            min-width:100%;
        }
        
        .content {
        position: relative;
        width:100%;
        min-height:100%;
        z-index:1000%;
        background-colour: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
        
            
        }
        
        .content h {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 65px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight:300;
            color:#fff;
            padding-top:15%;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        .content p {
            
            text-align:bottom;
            font-size:20px;
            
            color:#aaa;
        }
               
               </style>
           </head>
             
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        
        <body>
        
        //here I get the video source
        <div class="background-wrap" style="left: 6px; top: 0px">
        <video id="video-bg-elem" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
        <source src="project.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
        
        //here is the problem the one delete other..I want to get website inside of my video while is playing
        <div class="header">
          <h1>My Website</h1>
          <p>A website created by me.</p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="navbar">
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#">Link</a>
          <a href="#" class="right">Link</a>
        </div>
        
        <div class="row">
          <div class="side">
            <h2>About Me</h2>
            <h5>Photo of me:</h5>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
            <p>Some text about me in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim..</p>
            <h3>More Text</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame.</p>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div><br>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:60px;">Image</div>
          </div>
          <div class="main">
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <h5>Title description, Dec 7, 2017</h5>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
            <br>
            <h2>TITLE HEADING</h2>
            <h5>Title description, Sep 2, 2017</h5>
            <div class="fakeimg" style="height:200px;">Image</div>
            <p>Some text..</p>
            <p>Sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="footer">
          <h2>Footer</h2>
        </div>
        
        
        
        </body>

</html>
    
     <br><br>
    </div>
```

Comment: hmm, didnt get exactly? u want to have text on top of video?

Comment: @VenkateshKonatham I want to have on the header the video and inside the text website. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_make_a_website.asp.This is the link of w3school and I want on the header(there it says website ) to put my video.

Comment: I don't know why I can't post as comment the http code of w3school but I write how to make a website w3school on google.